# Skiing near Katmandu, Nepal

Tags: nepal, skiing, kathmandu

I will be travelling to Kathmandu (and onwards to Pokhara).

Is there some place where we can go for skiing which is drivable distance from these cities?

Comment: How far do you consider driveable?

Comment: @MarkMayo: Looking for less than a half a day of driving, one way. I have only a week in Nepal.

Answer (score 2):

Nepal has Heli-skiing, but no downhill ski resorts.  You can contact HHSG Heli Skiing (http://www.heliskinepal.com) for more details, but most of their offerings are multi-day packages for small groups.

Cross country skiing is also possible, but don't know of any specific businesses that can get you equipped with rental gear and out onto the trails.